# Tokenizing special characters in a string

Tags: java

I am working on some code and I have ran into issues regarding splitting up certain characters in a string. When given a string below, I can separate it into separate tokens:

```
String line = "hello world ; how are you ;"
```

such as hello, world, and ;

But when the code looks like:

```
String line2 = "hello world; how are you;"
```

I create tokens such as world; and you; when in reality I want the semicolon to be its own token. Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: What is your criteria for this?

Comment: What you want to do is called _lexical analysis_, and requires a little more work than just breaking a string apart at blanks.

Comment: I want to be given a String line2 = "Hello; World;" and be able to create an array that looks like ["Hello", ";", "World", ";"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to split the second line using word boundary and remove blank lines using filter:

```java
String line2 = "hello world; how are you;";

String[] arr = Arrays.stream(line2.split("\\b"))
      .filter(s -> !s.matches("\\s+"))
      .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[hello, world, ; , how, are, you, ;]
```

---

Another option could be to use matching substrings instead of splitting by delimiter.  The matching regular expression can be: 
`\w+|\S+` - at least one word character `[0-9A-Za-z_]` OR at least one non-space character:

```java
String[] arr2 = Pattern.compile("\\w+|\\S+")
                      .matcher(line2)
                      .results()
                      .map(mr -> mr.group(0))
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

The result is the same.